How are linedin api requests counted?
I am looking at the linkedin api and if I understood well I can use it freely if I do < 500 api requests per day. What is not clear is if the authentication requests are counted as part of these 500 requests or not?
Thanks
Googled and checked the official info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2 but no help there
